I wrote a C program which prints Hello World, but it closes before I can see the output. How can I add delay to see the output?
I'm new in the C programming language. I have GCC 6.3.0 as the compiler and use Notepad++ 8.5.7.0 for writing. I do not have an IDE. So I wrote my first in NP++ program which is
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
printf("Hello World!");
return 0;
}

This program would terminate without being able to read the output so I needed some ways to add some delay so as to see the program output.
After Googling for a while I came across the delay(ms) function. I tried to use it by :
#include<stdio.h>
#includ<stdlib.h>

int main(){
printf("Hello World!");
delay(2500);
return 0;
}

I expected this to add a 2.5 seconds delay before terminating. But instead of that, GCC gave the following error while compiling :
Hello.c: In function 'main':
Hello.c:21:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'delay' \[-Wimplicit-function-declaration\]
delay(2500);
^\~\~\~\~
C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ccDQtRCK.o:Hello.c:(.text+0xd0): undefined reference to \`delay'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

which says the delay function is not defined, as far as I understand.

Then I came across this block of code :
int c, d;
   
   for (c = 1; c <= 32767; c++)
       for (d = 1; d <= 32767; d++)
       {}

which basically runs a really long for loop. It does add notable delay after the program, however this makes my CPU and fans go crazy, probably because all of the incrementing going on. Are there any other ways I can add a delay to my program?

Just run the program from the command prompt rather than from your explorer window (which I presume you do).

There's no delay() function, but there's sleep(): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sleep-function-in-c/#

Ask for input from the user, e.g. "Please press Enter to continue..." or similar, and use char buffer[100]; fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);

On Windows you can do something like system("pause") I believe.

@Someprogrammerdude Or just getchar();. Not like the user cares about retrieving the input.

By far the most programs without a GUI do not wait for the user to confirm their end. Instead you run them from the command line and then you have all the time you need to read their output. Actually, users are heavily bothered if you implement a delay or confirmation.

It's highly abnormal to make a program delay before exiting. As others here have told you, fix the way you're starting it so the window doesn't close as soon as it's finished, don't try to make the program delay its finish. If you run almost any built-in command-line tool that came with Windows -- say dir -- you'll see they do the same thing your program is doing, because that's normal, expected behavior.

The error message you are seeing is telling that in your scope, the function delay is not defined (it doesn't exist).
Instead, you can use the function sleep, defined in unistd.h if you are on Linux or windows.h if you are on Windows (note that the behaviour of the function may change between the two platforms).
You can use it like this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> // this example will work on Linux

int main() {
    printf("Hello World!");
    // suspend execution for 2 seconds
    sleep(2); 
    return 0;
}

While on Windows the sleep function takes as argument milliseconds, on Linux the sleep function will only accept integers as arguments (this means that you will only be able to suspend execution for full seconds, not for half a second). Eventually, if you want to wait for a certain time in milliseconds on Linux, you can implement something like this, using the usleep function:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> // this example will work on Linux

void sleep_ms(int milliseconds) {
    // Convert milliseconds to microseconds
    usleep(milliseconds * 1000);
}

int main() {
    printf("Hello World!");
    sleep_ms(2500);
    return 0;
}

For more info on this functions, you can refer to this page.

I use windows but when I included <windows.h>, it gave an error. And it worked completely fine when I included <unistd.h>.  Weird. But it worked so thanks a lot for your help!

@SinanMertUluçay it really depends on the type of environment you are in and of the type of compiler you are using. As a student myself, always glad to help others!

Others have shown you several ways to pause or add a time delay to your program.
However, the correct way to run command line programs is by executing it on a terminal. That way your program will print its output to the terminal you are executing it on, remaining on the terminal's screen even after the program has finished its execution. Which means that no pause or delay needs to be added to your program.
In Windows' case you would usually run it in the Command Prompt (cmd.exe) or Powershell (powershell.exe) terminals. And the way I find the most practical to do it is by navigating to the program's folder on an Explorer window, and then click on the path navigation bar in Explorer, type cmd and press Enter, to open the Command Prompt terminal directly on the folder where your program is.

Then you just need to type the name of your program's executable in the terminal, and press Enter to run it.
C:\path\to\your\programs\folder>helloworld.exe

getchar() is the most portable way to add a pause in processing that I know.  getchar() waits for a *keypress before execution can continue. This code was compiled and tested by me before posting.  Please give it a try.
*EDIT: specifically, the ENTER keypress is needed.  Note that getch() (in conio.h) will take any keypress, but it is not available on all platforms.
Depending on the platform, other means of delaying processing exist.  Old 16-bit Borland compilers do have delay().  Current day Microsoft compilers have Sleep().  Both take a parameter in milliseconds.  For the Linux platform, the sleep() function takes a parameter in seconds.
If you are using one of these platforms, then simply replace the call to getchar() with the appropriate function from the list I just described, if you prefer a time-based delay to a keypress.
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}


getchar() waits for you to press Enter to continue with the code execution, not any keypress... If you press a letter or number key for instance it will actually type the key text in the command line, instead of continuing with the program instructions.

@isrnick -- yes true.  Thank you for this useful comment.

If there is a leftover newline character on the input stream (for example as a result of using scanf), then using getchar will not pause the program. It will return immediately. Therefore, I'm afraid that this solution will not work reliably in all situations.

@AndreasWenzel -- too true.  All: Please note getchar() is only one of many options discussed in my answer/solution.  getchar() was highlighted because it is portable, and like so many portable solutions, it has significant shortcomings.  The best solution will likely be another option I presented, but one which fits the individual's chosen platform.

As @gregspears says, getchar() is the way to go if you want to solve this within your code.
My advice is to configure your terminal so that it does not close when the program has finished.
